# How to use NSLogger Desktop Client without Mac Developer program membership

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, code-signing-certificate

I want to use the [NSLogger Desktop Client](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger/tree/master/Desktop%20Viewer).

I'm not a member of the Mac Developer Program, therefore I don't have a signing certificate. In the Xcode 5 Build Settings, I've set "Code Signing Identity" to "Don't Code Sign" and the "Provisioning Profile" to "none", but Xcode still complains "No code signing entity found."

Is there a binary distribution to download somewhere?

Comment: Update: Apple announced "The iOS Developer Program, Mac Developer Program, and Safari Developer Program are now the Apple Developer Program. Starting June 8 (2015), only one membership in the single Apple Developer Program is needed to build and distribute apps for iOS, OS X, and watchOS.": https://developer.apple.com/support/transition/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [CocoaPods](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger#podfile) section of the [NSLogger Github repo](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger) you can find a link for the last prebuilt desktop app.

For v1.5-Beta1 (last as of today) the link is [this one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zt1eyfgymc9fbak/NSLogger-1.2.zip)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, if you read a bit deeper you can see that they tell you how in the Wiki
here's the [link to building the Desktop Client](https://github.com/fpillet/NSLogger/wiki/Building-the-NSLogger-viewer)

Answer (score 1):

This is working well for me on OSX 10.9: http://macdownload.informer.com/nslogger/1.0/

Answer (score 1):

remove the 'code sign' then it can be build